# Signing into Google using AppAuth on Kindle

Tags: android

I am trying to sign in to Google using AppAuth since play services is not available on kindle devices. My problem is that I must use an Android clientID and we are sending our Auth token to a backend server to make the access token request for us. The problem is that the client ID on the back-end server is different (web client id). We can use the web client id with the GoogleSignIn API and it works fine on devices with play services installed.

Is there a way to use AppAuth with a web client id so our backend server and our apps can use the same client id?